# Downloaded clean repo or checkout branch and git says something changed

Tags: git

I have few branches in my Git repo and people from my Team says that sometimes they download a clean copy or repo and checkout branch or pushing something then checkout branch then Git says that some files are modified but when we look into the changes nothing change.

What is going on here? 
I may be because Bitlocker on yours machines?

**git diff on sample file**

```
    @@ -5,12 +5,12 @@ webpackJsonp([0],{

 "use strict";
 /* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "a", function() { return CONFIG; });
-var CONFIG = {
-    baseUrls: {
-        vehicles: 'src/api/vehicles.json',
-        characters: 'src/api/characters.json'
-    }
-};
+var CONFIG = {
+    baseUrls: {
+        vehicles: 'src/api/vehicles.json',
+        characters: 'src/api/characters.json'
+    }
+};
 //# sourceMappingURL=config.js.map

 /***/ })
```

As you see nothing changed...

Comment: When you change from the default to new branch may some file is moved away from control, but it still exists, hence shows as a untracked file.

Comment: Possibly EOL issues

Comment: @CristianoAraujo what do you mean?

Comment: say foo.c is under control in master, but don't exist in develop, if you checkout develop from master, foo.c will be kept on the source tree, but will show as untracked file on index.

Comment: @CristianoAraujo, nah they are in modified state in working dir.

Answer (score 0):

Line endings and white space. Git records all characters in a file, including invisible ones. What you're seeing there is likely line ending changes - maybe from \r\n to \n or vise-versa. Different operating systems use different line endings.

Fixes:

1. configure editors to use the same ending
2. configure git to convert line endings on commit https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: We use the same OS and Visual Studio and Git sorce control plugin.

Comment: Even if we don't modify the file its possible to got the eol problem?